# Android Line chart/graph API

Tags: android, graph, charts, linechart, linegraph

I need to show progressive numeric stats to my Line Graph/Chart. Please share your opinion and advice. Please also make a note that I prefer if there would be a native API.

rohit

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any good graphing packages for Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android)

Comment: Simple example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543739/how-to-draw-a-graph-in-android-using-graphview/26562713#26562713

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AChartEngine is a charting library for Android applications. It currently supports the following chart types:

line chart
area chart
scatter chart
time chart
bar chart
pie chart
bubble chart
doughnut chart
range (high-low) bar chart
dial chart / gauge
combined (any combination of line, cubic line, scatter, bar, range bar, bubble) chart
cubic line chart
You can get more information from [this link](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/).

Comment: I find a few bugs with the text on portrait layout, it stretches

So, if you have the same problem, There is a good open source library with the AChartEngine bug-fixes and easy to customize via layout.xml

https://github.com/melanke/MlkAndroidChartApi

you only need to take a look at the example code, it is very easy to use

Comment: @melanke has been warned and had their answers deleted for linking to their own project without disclosing that fact.

Comment: Im trying to help people to know a library I ve made because I find a issue on other libraries. I will have no profit on this. Whats the problem on this?

Comment: The problem is, Stack Overflow is not here to be a place to promote your projects. It doesn't matter if you 'profit' in it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Zeitdata Charts](http://charts.zeitdata.com). It is very lean and offers line charts and scatter plots. It also allows you to see what a chart would look like from within a layout editor.