# Incorporating HTML and Javascript components into Android application

Tags: javascript, android, html, graph

I am developing an Android app and would like to add a few existing web graphs to some of the pages of the app. The graphs are currently defined in HTML and externally depend on CSS and Javascript. I would like to know the best way to port these graphs to my app but do not know any best practices and have never used graphs in Android before. An example of the graph looks like this:

[image]

I know that I can create an html file in /assests and populate a WebView with it:

```
    WebView wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    wb.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/example.html");
```

However, I am not sure if this will allow me to incorporate the necessary Javascript with the HTML elements or if this is even best practice. I should also add that the graph needs to be dynamically generated from data stored on the device.

Any tips, help, or advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you tried it in a WebView, what happened?

Comment: The code for this graph is fairly complex and was not working after embedding the javascript and CSS but I have not taken the time to try to find the problem. However when adding simple html to example.html the WebView displayed it perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with a native charts api like http://androidplot.com/ (the first one I found on google, I'm sure there are more). Using a WebView and Javascript ist okay but if you need the charts generated dynamically from data on the device, I think it will be simpler and more straight forward to use a native api.

Also see this SO question: [Android Line chart/graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680469/android-line-chart-graph-api)

Comment: The only thing that's keeping me from using native charts is that I want to keep the styles and functionality from my existing webcharts.

Comment: You can of course go the way of using a WebView but it will always be a bit of an alien inside your app and especially passing data from your native part to the WebView for rendering (perhaps via dynamically generated Javascript or whatever) will always be a bit of a quirks, so I think on the long run you'd be better of with a native approach.